# Create dataset of XYZ positions on a given plane

Tags: c++, 3d, geometry, computational-geometry, linear-algebra

I need to create a list of XYZ positions given a starting point and an offset between the positions based on a plane. On just a flat plane this is easy. Let's say the offset I need is to move down 3 then right 2 from position 0,0,0

The output would be:

```
0,0,0 (starting position)
0,-3,0 (move down 3)
2,-3,0 (then move right 2)
```

The same goes for a different start position, let's say 5,5,1:

```
5,5,1 (starting position)
5,2,1 (move down 3)
7,2,1 (then move right 2)
```

The problem comes when the plane is no longer on this flat grid.

I'm able to calculate the equation of the plane and the normal vector given 3 points. 
But now what can I do to create this dataset of XYZ locations given this equation?

I know I can solve for XYZ given two values. Say I know x=1 and y=1, I can solve for Z. But moving down 2 is no longer just y-2. I believe I need to find a linear equation on both the x and y axis to increment the positions and move parallel to the x and y of this new plane, then just solve for Z. I'm not sure how to accomplish this.

The other issue is that I need to calculate the angle, tilt and rotation of this plane in relation to the base plane.

For example:

```
P1=0,0,0 and P2=1,1,0 the tilt=0deg angle=0deg rotation=45deg.
P1=0,0,0 and P2=0,1,1 the tilt=0deg angle=45deg rotation=0deg.
P1=0,0,0 and P2=1,0,1 the tilt=45deg angle=0deg rotation=0deg.
P1=0,0,0 and P2=1,1,1 the tilt=0deg angle=45deg rotation=45deg.
```

I've searched for hours on both these problems and I've always come to a stop at the equation of the plane. Manipulating the x,y correctly to follow parallel to the plane, and then taking that information to find these angles. This is a lot of geometry to be solved, and I can't find any further information on how to calculate this list of points, let alone calculating the 3 angles to the base plane.

I would appericate any help or insight on this. Just plain old math or a reference to C++ would be perfect to sheding some light onto this issue I'm facing here.

Thank you,
Matt

Comment: Hi there! Just wanted to clarify some things - what do you mean by "up" "down" "left" and "right" in a context that is no longer 2D? I think that is the root cause of your confusion. When you say "down", do you now mean 3 units in the opposite direction of the (+) normal vector to the plane? or 3 units in the -z_hat direction? If you clarify this, the rest becomes quite simple.

Comment: The other thing I wanted to clarify was what you mean by "tilt" "angle" and "rotation". There are many ways of producing a new orientation of a rigid body, but generally people think of Euler Angles as their rotation operations. (there are others such as Roll Pitch Yaw - Tait Bryant, etc)

Comment: Akshaya, I can see how there is no reference to up,down,left,right. What I'd like to do is move parallel to the sides of the plane. Here's a crappy paint image to illustrate this [Plane Image](http://i.imgur.com/c3U47.png). So from P1 I want to move parallel to S1 to the point in blue. Then move parallel to S2 to the point in green.

Answer (score 1):

You can think of your plane as being defined by a point and a pair of [orthonormal basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthonormal_basis) vectors (which just means two vectors of length 1, 90 degrees from one another).  Your most basic plane can be defined as:

```
p0 = (0, 0, 0) #Origin point
vx = (1, 0, 0) #X basis vector
vy = (0, 1, 0) #Y basis vector
```

To find point `p1` that's offset by `dx` in the X direction and `dy` in the Y direction, you use this formula:

```
p1 = p0 + dx * vx + dy * vy
```

This formula will always work if your offsets are along the given axes (which it sounds like they are).  This is still true if the vectors have been rotated - that's the property you're going to be using.

So to find a point that's been offset along a rotated plane:

1. Take the default basis vectors (`vx` and `vy`, above).
2. Rotate them until they define the plane you want (you may or may not need to rotate the origin point as well, depending on how the problem is defined).
3. Apply the formula, and get your answer.

Now there are some quirks when you're doing rotation (Order matters!), but that's the the basic idea, and should be enough to put you on the right track.  Good luck!

Comment: Xavier, your explanation makes perfect sense. How can I define the X & Y basis vectors given the plane equation and normal vector? Thanks!

Comment: @Matt - Unfortunately, I'm not sure that you can.  The problem with "point + normal" form is that you can treat the normal as an axis of rotation, spin the plane around that axis any arbitrary angle, and be left with the same plane (as far as the point + normal representation is concerned), even though the X and Y axes _within_ the plane have changed.  Ideally you'd start with a "point + rotation from the basic XY plane" representation (and that's what your last example shows - are you sure you don't have it in that form?).

Comment: Xavier, so let's say I just have 3 XYZ points, without getting into the plane equation or normal vector, is there a way to get the vx,vy from these positions? I have the following example [here](http://i.imgur.com/qSOxk.png). How would I get the two vectors from this example? I tried setting the 3 points as p0,vx,vy which didn't seem to work with the Z. Thank you, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @Matt - No problem.  Say you've got three points: `p1`, `p2`, and `p3`.  Pick any one of them to use as `p0` - I'll pick `p2`.  subtract that point from the other two to get your vectors: `v1 = p1 - p2` and `v2 = p3 - p2`.  To get an orthonormal basis from those, you can use the [Gram-Schmidt Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram-schmidt).  Sadly, though, this is plagued by the same ambiguity as the point + normal version: you don't know how the plane is rotated relative to its normal.  If you'd chosen a different point as `p0`, you'd have gotten a different basis.

Comment: @Matt - Can you describe exactly what information you have to start with?  I could (maybe) be more helpful if I knew how the problem was defined.

Comment: There is a base plane and a flat surface that somewhere above this plane. I have 3 XYZ coordinates that define this flat surface. I need to be able to move parallel and square along this surface. Also, knowing how this surface is tilted in relation to the base plane. What information would I need to make this possible? Thanks again!

Comment: @Matt - Got it, I think.  You don't have enough info to find rotation around a normal, but you can find the minimum rotation that makes one plane parallel to the other.  Take the two unit normals, `n1` and `n2`.  The axis of rotation is their cross product.  The angle of rotation is the arc cosine of their dot product.  That gives you the [Axis-Angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axis_and_angle) form of the rotation, and if you need it in a different format, just Google the conversion - they're tedious, but they're straightforward.  Cheers!